# Liquid If clause code needed for Shopify

Tags: shopify

I'm creating a webshop page in Shopify and I would like to make an If or For clause.

What I want to achieve : I want to hide the add to cart (+Winkelwagen) button every time the first option is selected and I want this for each product (every product will have the same value/option of '1') Why does it have the value of 1?The answer to that question is, because my colleagues under sales need the option of bulk sales. So for example each product has 3 options of quantity.

Option 1 36 pieces for 203 euros
Option 2 90 pieces for 393 euros
Option 3 240 pieces for 856 euros

**Problem is when I set the 3 options the original price FOR 1 piece disappears** So I created another option and assigned it to the top so the client can see the price for 1 (see screenshots http://prntscr.com/fmrfkk http://prntscr.com/fmrfvk )

so it becomes like this

Option 1 1 pieces for 3.57 euros
Option 2 36 pieces for 203 euros
Option 3 90 pieces for 393 euros
Option 4 240 pieces for 856 euros

My idea was to hide the add to cart button each time 'option 1' is selected so the client can NOT order 1 piece. Can someone show me how to do the coding ? Thanks !

Comment: Hi Christopher You can do this by Updating quantity values by "2" instead of "1"  in cart-Templet and Product-Templet Page. And I sure It would work Fine.

Comment: Have you tried not giving 1 piece as a variant.. In practice there are only three variants of your product "36, 90 and 240"